# Passing Excel Sheet name into macro VB

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I think this should be a simple one considering I have very little VB knowledge :)  I have recorded a macro to create a pivot table for a range on the current sheet.  Of course what this gives me is the code to create a pivot table for that specific sheet.  I am trying to adjust the code to grab the name of the active sheet so I can use this macro across different sheets.  I have tried to search and find exactly how to retrieve the name and then supply that name to the code that will being the process of creating the pivot table.

I am hitting a roadblock at the ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create section of the code.  I am getting the "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sht As String
sht = ActiveSheet.Name

    Columns("A:K").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Worksheets(sht).Range("!R1C1:R1048576C11"), Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        Worksheets(sht).Range("!R1C14"), TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Cells(1, 14).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Department")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields( _
        "Originating Master Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Net")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Net"), "Count of Net", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Count of Net")
        .Caption = "Sum of Net"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am currently using Excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
Worksheets(sht).Range("!R1C1:R1048576C11")
```

To this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range("A1:K1048576")
```

And this

```
 Worksheets(sht).Range("!R1C14")
```

To this

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range("N1")
```

Comment: That worked!!!  Thanks so much!  Would you mind giving me a brief description of issue with the range?

Comment: Glad it we found the answer! What your macro would have recorded would have been something like "Sheet5!R1C12:R4C5" , note that the entire range reference is inside the "".  When you created you range using the variable you had Worksheets(sht).Range("!R1C1:R1048576C11"). This isn't a valid Range construction as the error indicated. The ! indicated the end of the Worksheet object i.e. Sheet5!

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks again QHarr!